# .Net Core Unexpected NuGet Behavior

Tags: .net, windows, nuget, windows-10, .net-core

I [installed .net core from this site](https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) and followed the three step instructions for testing a "hello world" console application:

```
dotnet new
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

Everything worked, and the console app ran successfully.

Nevertheless, the `restore` step did two unexpected things.  First, it restored packages to NuGet's global package folder (`%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`).  This kind of **global install** has never before been a default behavior for NuGet.  Granted, if `dotnet restore` is internally using nuget.exe...this behavior might be due to the lack of a Visual Studio solution file.

However, this only underscores the second unexpected behavior. The `restore` operation installed 85 packages into the global NuGet packages folder.  Practically all of these packages were not needed by the sample console application.

Seemingly, this completely contradicts all that is claimed for .Net Core.

For example, for this simple "hello world" console app, here are some of the packages that were installed:

- runtime.win7.System.Net.Sockets
- System.Globalization.Calendars
- System.Linq

So that there is not doubt of what I mean by *simple 'hello world' console app*, here is the entire program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

What I expected is that the number of packages needed by the sample console app would be between 0 and 3-ish.  And again, per the claims of .Net Core, I expected the NuGet packages to be installed locally - in the same folder as the sample console app itself.

Can someone please clarify why or how this behavior does not contradict the claims of .Net Core?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have dotnet installed on this machine but, if I remember correctly, the app created by `dotnet new` references `NETStandard.Library` which is an "umbrella" package that has a lot of dependencies. You can replace it with the `System.*` dependencies that your app needs and you'll get less packages on restore.

If your application depends on X packages then it will probably restore more than X because it needs to bring all the dependencies of those packages too. That's why you see a lot of packages restored.

If you want to install the packages locally, you can specify the packages folder when you run `dotnet restore` and then set the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable for runtime.

Comment: I think it is important to note that in .NET Core all dependencies are transitive. Which means that if you include a package in your app, you also include all packages on which your dependency depends on. Like that one package (like the standard library or the Asp.NET MVC package) can import a complete app model or base library. There are dragons :)

Answer (score 0):

The packages are installed to `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` for caching purposes. As Microsoft are moving towards making everything a package (System.* etc), it makes sense to not download packages every time you create a new project.

If you look at runtime.win7.System.Net.Sockets package on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.win7.System.Net.Sockets), you'll see a dependency on System.Private.Networking. That in turn has a [dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Private.Networking/) on quite a few packages.

[image]

The packages that were installed probably match these.